# Another 14.04 login loop problem

Tags: 14.04, login

Upgraded desk top to 14.04 and encountered the login loop problem. Everything I've read says to login on the terminal but I can not do that either. It will say "login unsuccessful". For kicks I tried to login on the terminal on my laptop that has 15.04 but I am having the same "login unsuccessful". What am I doing wrong here?
Note: 1. I am new to Ubuntu 2. Everything else works on my laptop I just need to figure out what is going on with my desk top

Answer (score 0):

As a start I would recommend booting the machine into single-user mode, as described for example at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode.  This should get you a command line with root access.

From here you can check some of the possible causes of the problem.  It would probably good to look at recent error messages in system log files. I see various causes associated with this problem, see for example [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop).

Hope this helps.